# Exporting postgres data to pdf file

Tags: php, postgresql, pdf

I am having a hard time generating a PDF file from data in a postgres database.

I have been able to generate the excel file correctly, but I can't do the same with PDF.

Here it is the excel I generate. How can I do the same but send it to pdf?

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=QuickList.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");

include_once("C:/webroot/connect.php");
$user=$_SESSION['username'];

//loop the query data to the table in same order as the headers
$sql_data = "SELECT agent, study, ind_no, sponsor, status 
             FROM dw_regtrack.qlstudies st 
             LEFT JOIN dw_regtrack.user_studies us ON st.study=us.study_name 
             WHERE user_name='$user'";

/*$sql_data2="SELECT study, amtrackid, name, pi, status, irbappcr, ohrp, ib, prot, ic, global1572, 1572, ibc, obarac, dsa 
            FROM dw_regtrack.qlstudysites2";*/

$sql_data2="select study, amtrackid, name, pi, dsa, status, 
        CASE WHEN irbappcr = '1' THEN 'yes' WHEN irbappcr = '3' THEN 'n/a' ELSE 'no' END as irbappcr, 
        CASE WHEN ibc = '1' THEN 'yes' WHEN ibc = '3' THEN 'n/a' ELSE 'no' END as ibc, 
        CASE WHEN obarac = '1' THEN 'yes' WHEN obarac = '3' THEN 'n/a' ELSE 'no' END as obarac, 
        CASE WHEN ohrp = '1' THEN 'yes' WHEN ohrp = '3' THEN 'n/a' ELSE 'no' END as ohrp,       
        CASE WHEN ib = '1' THEN 'yes' WHEN ib = '3' THEN 'n/a' ELSE 'no' END as ib, 
        CASE WHEN prot = '1' THEN 'yes' WHEN prot = '3' THEN 'n/a' ELSE 'no' END as prot, 
        CASE WHEN ic = '1' THEN 'yes' WHEN ic = '3' THEN 'n/a' ELSE 'no' END as ic, 
        CASE WHEN global1572 = '1' THEN 'yes' WHEN global1572 = '3' THEN 'n/a' ELSE 'no' END as global1572,     
        CASE WHEN \"1572\" = '1' THEN 'yes' WHEN \"1572\" = '3' THEN 'n/a' ELSE 'no' END as \"1572\" 
        FROM dw_regtrack.qlstudysites2";

/*$sql_data3="SELECT amtrackid, labid, name, cap, clia, lnv 
            FROM dw_regtrack.qlstudysitelabs";*/
$sql_data3="SELECT amtrackid,labid,name,
            CASE WHEN cap = '1' THEN 'yes' WHEN cap = '3' THEN 'n/a' ELSE 'no' END as cap,
            CASE WHEN clia = '1' THEN 'yes' WHEN clia = '3' THEN 'n/a' ELSE 'no' END as clia,
            CASE WHEN lnv = '1' THEN 'yes' WHEN lnv = '3' THEN 'n/a' ELSE 'no' END as lnv 
            FROM dw_regtrack.qlstudysitelabs";

/*$sql_data4="SELECT amtrackid, personid, name, cv, ml, fd, hspt, dot, pisort 
            FROM dw_regtrack.qlstudysiteinvests2";*/

$sql_data4="SELECT amtrackid,personid, name,
            CASE WHEN cv = '1' THEN 'yes' WHEN cv = '3' THEN 'n/a' ELSE 'no' END as cv,
            CASE WHEN ml = '1' THEN 'yes' WHEN ml = '3' THEN 'n/a' ELSE 'no' END as ml,
            CASE WHEN fd = '1' THEN 'yes' WHEN fd = '3' THEN 'n/a' ELSE 'no' END as fd,
            CASE WHEN dot = '1' THEN 'yes' WHEN dot = '3' THEN 'n/a' ELSE 'no' END as dot,
            CASE WHEN hspt = '1' THEN 'yes' WHEN hspt = '3' THEN 'n/a' ELSE 'no' END as hspt,pisort 
            FROM dw_regtrack.qlstudysiteinvests2";

$result=pg_query($sql_data);

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC)){
    echo implode("\t", array('Agent', 'Study', 'IND No', 'IND Sponsor', 'Current Status'))."\r\n";
    echo implode("\t", array($row['agent'], $row['study'], $row['ind_no'],$row['sponsor'], $row['status'])) . "\r\n";

    $result2=pg_query($sql_data2." WHERE study = '".$row['study']."'");
    while ($row2=pg_fetch_array($result2, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        echo implode("\t", array('','Site', 'PI', 'Status', 'IRBappcr', 'OHRP', 'IB', 'PROT', 'IC', 'Global1572', '1572', 'IBC', 'OBARAC', 'DSA'))."\r\n";
        echo implode("\t", array('',$row2['name'], $row2['pi'], $row2['status'], $row2['irbappcr'], $row2['ohrp'], $row2['ib'], $row2['prot'], $row2['ic'], $row2['global1572'], $row2['1572'], $row2['ibc'], $row2['obarac'], $row2['dsa']))."\r\n";

        $result3=pg_query($sql_data3." WHERE amtrackid= '".$row2['amtrackid']."'");     
        echo implode("\t", array('','','Lab', 'CAP', 'CLIA', 'LNV'))."\r\n";
        while ($row3=pg_fetch_array($result3, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC)){
            echo implode("\t", array('','',$row3['name'], $row3['cap'], $row4['clia'],$row4['lnv']))."\r\n";
        }

        $result4=pg_query($sql_data4." WHERE amtrackid= '".$row2['amtrackid']."'"); 
        echo implode("\t", array('','','Investigator', 'CV', 'ML', 'FD', 'HSPT', 'DOT'))."\r\n";
        while ($row4=pg_fetch_array($result4, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC)){
            echo implode("\t", array('','',$row4['name'], $row4['cv'], $row4['ml'],$row4['fd'], $row4['hspt'],$row4['dot']))."\r\n";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to create a PDF with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132015/best-way-to-create-a-pdf-with-php)